# Using jQuery, how can you trigger an event from a child window, in the parent window?

Tags: jquery, triggers, window, parent

Basically I want to call a function in the parent window. I thought I could hook an event handler to a function I want to run in the parent... any thoughts how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

window.opener.parent.function() does the trick, but in my case I needed to keep a copy of window because the context changed when I used setTimeout.

```
    var _window = window;
    setTimeout( function(){             
        //location.reload(true);
        _window.opener.invite_child_response();
        _window.close();                    
    },5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

From child window, use

```
parent.MyFunction()
```

Comment: Perhaps. Check trigger() function implementation.